# Bind variable for date

Tags: oracle, variables, plsql, bind

I am writing procedure where I need to send an out refcursor.

Here are the variable declarations:

```
v_def_cycle_start_date   date;
v_def_cycle_end_date     date
```

Based on some criteria we compute `v_def_cycle_start_date` and `v_def_cycle_end_date` in the code. We use them at the end. So I want to pass this as bind variable. But the date variable is not taking the effect.

```
open results for 
 'SELECT tt.bd_iid,tt.make_iid,tta.aux_entity_iid,tta.quantity
    FROM txn_tab tt,txn_tab_amount tta,eli_txn r,
         export_date pts,
   WHERE tt.txn_tab_iid = tta.txn_tab_iid
     AND tt.channel = 2
     AND tt.txn_tab_iid = r.txn_tab_iid
     AND r.elig = 1
     AND EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 FROM txn_eod t
            WHERE tt.txn_eod_iid = t.txn_eod_iid
            AND t.end_date BETWEEN nvl(pts.cycle_end_date,:v_def_cycle_start_date) +(1 / 86400)  AND  (:v_def_cycle_end_date))'
     using v_def_cycle_start_date , v_def_cycle_end_date
```

Can please help how to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this alternative approach. Hope it helps.

```
DECLARE
  result sys_refcursor;
  v_def_cycle_start_date DATE;
  v_def_cycle_end_date   DATE;
BEGIN
  OPEN results FOR 'SELECT tt.bd_iid,tt.make_iid,tta.aux_entity_iid,tta.quantity    
FROM txn_tab tt,txn_tab_amount tta,eli_txn r,         
export_date pts,   
WHERE tt.txn_tab_iid = tta.txn_tab_iid     
AND tt.channel = 2     
AND tt.txn_tab_iid = r.txn_tab_iid     
AND r.elig = 1     
AND EXISTS    
(SELECT 1 FROM txn_eod t            
WHERE tt.txn_eod_iid = t.txn_eod_iid            
AND t.end_date BETWEEN nvl(pts.cycle_end_date,'||''''||v_def_cycle_start_date||''''||' +(1 / 86400))  AND  ('||''''||v_def_cycle_end_date||''''||')';
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for the Solution.  I tried its  throwing error of invalid format , as i m using few more bind variables not only dates

Comment: What kind of input u have. As this error clearly states the date format issue